# Resource caching through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, caching

### My code

I put this .htaccess code into the root folder of my website:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 777600 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 604800 seconds"
```

### What the code should do

Caching images, flash objects and css, javascript and css files to the browser of users.

### What's not working

If I run an audit with google chrome for some of the files (two `.jpg` images and two `.css` files) that should be cached due to the code, I'm told:

> The following resources are missing a cache expiration. Resources that
>   do not specify an expiration may not be cached by browsers

If I reload the page without leaving it and re-run the audit, I'm told:

> The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime

### My question

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this [article on askapache](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html) a read. It seems the syntax is a little different from the example you supplied. Hope it helps.

Comment: Using http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html#Apache_htaccess_caching_code I get 500 error
mod_expires and mod_headers are not installed on my hosting :(

Comment: That's too bad, you really need those to set this up. Ask your hoster if he would like to help, he benefits too by having the server less loaded, which means he can put more sites on to the same server.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm going to ask them. Thanks for your answer